# Undefined constant "RestClient" after rest-client gem has been installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Just added `gem "rest-client", "~> 1.6.7"` to my gem file and ran bundle install.

Trying to make the app send a get request to a local jetty

```
@server = "http://127.0.0.1:3333"
RestClient.get @server+'/command/core/get-version'
```

results in

> uninitialized constant XController::RestClient

**UPDATE:**
Question solved, I forgot to restart the webserver.

Comment: Have your restarted your server after adding gem?

Comment: @BroiSatse, no, I have not. Will try now

Comment: Than probably that's the reason - gems are being loaded on server start.

Comment: you should probably either answer your own question then or delete the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that it requires to restart the server for freshly installed gems to come in effect.

Answer (score 4):

Outside rails, I ran into the same problem. Solution:

```
require 'rest-client'
```

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me few times i named the gem `restclient` instead of `rest-client` :) Both gems exist, but the one with dash is the correct one.